# how to fit tab to the width of a paper using tabular

Tags: tables

For the layout of a table, how could I meet the following two criteria at the same time ?

1. Fit the width of table to the textwdith
2. Be able to allocate the width of table to each column (not evenly allocated).

Answer (score 4):

If you want say a three column table with columns in ratio 1:2:2  then use

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylength}p{2\mylength}p{2\mylength}@{}}
```

where you want `5\mylength+4\tabcolsep=\textwidth` so

```
\newlength\mylength
\mylength=\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\tabcolsep)/5\relax
```